# How to make UIIamgeView move smoothly?

Tags: xcode

there.I have some display promblem about xocde.

When I using UIView and UIIamgeView bulid up my game.
I found the finally result looks like a little weird.
It looks like laggy or not smoothly.

It will be fine when move speed it's really low.
But when the value over 3 (even only FPS30), it will become visible.
I checked out many games, they don't have this problem even they move faster then mine.

I used to use only one update in the main controlling everything.
Then I call the update by NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval.And change UIView or UIImageView by CGAffineTransform or change it's own frame, depends on what I need.

How can I solve this problem?Any suggestion?Thanks.

ps.I tried many ways, include UIView Animation, UIScrollView, OpenGL, but still got the same problem.And please forgive my poor english.